# Java query code for mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

Can Some one help toconvert this mongo query into java code ?
It works fine in mongo command line ,but I am not able run this with java . 
Here is mongo query

```
db.booking.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "bookingDate": {
                "$ne": null,
                "$gte": new Date("2017-04-01"),
                "$lte": new Date("2018-03-31")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "totalAmount": 1,
            "totalPax": 1,
            "month": {
                "$month": {
                    $add: ["$bookingDate", 25200000]
                }
            }

        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$month",
            "totalPax": {
                "$sum": "$totalPax"
            },
            "totalAmount": {
                "$sum": "$totalAmount"
            },

        }
    }
])
```

This is what I have tried , but its not working ,

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDate",
    new BasicDBObject("$gte", OperationsUtil.getISODateFromUIDate(startDate)).append("$lte",OperationsUtil.getISODateFromUIDate(endDate)).append("$ne", null)));
BasicDBObject match1 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDeleted",false));
BasicDBList add=new BasicDBList();
add.add(new BasicDBObject("$bookingDate",25200000));
BasicDBObject monthDoc=new BasicDBObject("$add",add);
BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",new BasicDBObject("_id",0).append("totalAmount",1).append("totalPax",1).append("month",new BasicDBObject("$month",monthDoc)));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id","$month")
.append("totalPaxCount", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$totalPax")).append("totalAmount",new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$totalAmount")));
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
AggregationOutput cursor = bookingCollection.aggregate(match,match1,project,group,sort);
```

Comment: What have you tried? This really is as simple as using `Document` whenever you see `{}` and `List` wherever you see `[]`. That's it.

Comment: @NeilLunn edited question with java tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we were able to convert the above query  solution , here is the code for the above query , just answering so that if someone  come across this kind problem can refer this answer

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDate", 
                new BasicDBObject("$gte", OperationsUtil.getISODateFromUIDate(startDate)).append("$lte",OperationsUtil.getISODateFromUIDate(endDate)).append("$ne", null)));
     BasicDBObject match1 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDeleted",false).append("tour.travelStatus",new BasicDBObject("$ne", "Unreceipted")));
     BasicDBList addition=new BasicDBList();
     addition.add("$bookingDate");
     addition.add(OperationsConstant.UTC_TO_IST_MILLISECONDS);
     BasicDBObject monthDoc=new BasicDBObject("$add",addition);
     BasicDBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",new BasicDBObject("_id",0).append("totalAmount",1).append("totalPax",1).append("month",new BasicDBObject("$month",monthDoc)));
     DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id","$month")
             .append("totalPaxCount", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$totalPax")).append("totalAmount",new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$totalAmount")));
     DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
     AggregationOutput cursor = bookingCollection.aggregate(match,match1,project,group,sort);
```